# how to identify a file name is 8.3 short file name

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if there is a function that can identify if the file name is short file name (8.3 file name).
I don't want the full path of the file but just a way to identify if the given filename is following the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename convention.
So my input to the function would be just the filename and i need to output boolean yes or no. 
e.g.:

file: *description.htm*, output: no

file *descri~1.htm*, *descri2~.htm*, output: yes.

Comment: what do you mean by `8.3 file name`? can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: This is difficult just given the name of the file. If the file includes the full path, then you can use API functions to get the full file name and verify that the file exists, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364980(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Given a file name and no physical file that exists for that name, you can't do this, for example TEXTFI~1.txt is both a valid 8.3 SFN and a valid full file name. It would pass both tests. The tilde is not a reserved character for file naming conventions, and some file systems are allowed to use other characters. Without checking against a physical file, you can't tell if its just the name of the file, or a SFN according to 8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about windows (what with the short file name 'n' all) you could use : GetShortPathName.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx

then compare the two.

Unless you literally mean - just has this string got a format of 8 character name and 3 character extension - in which case that should be easy to work out.

To just determine the format you could use regex (in c# - other regex's are available):

```
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^\S{1,8}\.\S{1,3}$");
        r.IsMatch("somefile.ext");
```

This should get you started - but you may want to massage the regex string a little.

Try https://regex101.com/ for a decent on line regex thingy ma bob.

Comment: I dont want the short path name for the given file name but a way to identify if the file name is short path or not . may be a way to see if the filename follows this convention 6 character followed by ~ followed by digit .extension

Comment: To be 8.3 complient I don't think the `.` or the last 3 are required. Also `\S` includes some invalid characters. like `.`

Answer (score 2):

You could use GetShortPathName in kernel32.dll to convert to a short path name and then check whether it returns the same string.

You have to declare the following to be able to access this function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern Int32 GetShortPathName(String path, StringBuilder shortPath, Int32 shortPathLength);
```

then you create a StringBuilder and call GetShortPathName:

```
StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(myPath.Length + 1);

PathExtensions.GetShortPathName(myPath, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
if (myPath == shortPath.ToString()) {
    //short path name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public static bool Is83(string fileName)
{
    var parts = Path.GetFileName(fileName).Split('.');
    return parts.Length == 2 && parts[0].Length <= 8 && parts[1].Length <= 3;
}
```

Comment: Apparently he wants `parts[1].Length <= 3 && parts[0].Length == 8 && parts[0][6] == '~'`.

Comment: No. With a 8.3 filename parts[1].Length is <=3 and parts[0].Length <= 8, it doesn't need to be 8 with a ~n - assumng it is a valid filename already. For example a.txt is a valid 8.3 name.

Comment: Of course you're right, an 8.3 filename doesn't need that.  But it sounds like the tilde test is what the asker really wants.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a regex to tell whether a whole path is 8.3.

```
^[A-Z]:\\(?:[^\\ ]{1,8}(?:\.[^\\ ]{1,3})?\\)+[^\\ ]{1,8}(?:\.[^\\ ]{1,3})?$
```

Comment: This still allows for a lot of characters that are not valid in a simple 8.3 path, including ? \ / and extra dots. Even if you rely on the OS to ensure that you don't have illegal filename/path characters, this would still match on characters outside of the ASCII range, which are not valid in an 8.3 name.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the accepted answer to weed out the invalid non-printing characters, the space (0x20) and anything above the ASCII range, here is a regex that will do the trick:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,8}(\.[\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,3})?$");
r.IsMatch("somefile.ext");
```

It's a little ugly, but I think this is the regex to use to check the entire (optionally rooted) path:

```
^([A-Za-z]:\\)?([\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,8}(\.[\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,3})?\\)*[\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,8}(\.[\x21-\x2D\x30-\x39\x3B-\x3E\x40-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]{1,3})?$
```

Note that this is potentially needed because unfortunately PathExtensions.GetShortPathName is not guaranteed to work. There is a property on system volumes can be set to not supply 8.3 names. So if you really need an 8.3 name, this regex will tell you if you got one.